# Markov Chain: memoryless property?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have a question about the Markov Chain. We were doing derivation of the Chapman-Kolmogorov Equations, the $n+m$ step state transition probability (please see below):

[image]

where $P_{i,j}$ is the probability transition from state $i$ to state $j$. In particular, I am confuse about the part highlighted in yellow.

$P(X_{n+m}=j|X_{n}=k,X_{0}=i)=P^m_{j,k}$

I do understand the time stationary of Markov Chain. What I don't understand is the Memoryless-Property.

So is it true that $P(X_{n+m}=j|X_{n}=k,X_{0}=i)=P(X_{n+m}=j|X_{n}=k)$?
The reason is because that $X_0$ is the initial state so that we can ignore it?

---

PS: What happen if we have another state $X_{n+1}$, and I have $P(X_{n+m}=j|X_{n+1}=b,X_{n}=k,X_{0}=i)$, can I say it is equal to $P(X_{n+m}=j|X_{n+1}=b)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditioned on any state, the progression of a Markov chain is independent of any earlier state, so yes,

$$
P(X_{n+m} = j \mid X_n = k, X_0 = i) = P(X_{n+m} = j \mid X_n = k)
$$

and that means also that you are right, that

$$
P(X_{n+m} = j \mid X_{n+1}
    = b, X_n = k, X_0 = i) = P(X_{n+m} = j \mid X_{n+1} = b)
$$

Comment: The textbook says $P(X_{n+1}=j|X_{n}=i_{n},X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},...., X_{0}=i_{0})=P(X_{n+1}=j|X_{n}=i_{n})$. It looks like the probability only depends on the state "right before it" ($X_{n+1}$ compares to $X_{n}$). But in the question, we don't have the state "right before it". So can I interpretate it as depending on the "latest" state?

Comment: Yes, conditioned on the latest state, future states are independent of earlier states.